# How to get a black hexagon symbol?

Tags: symbols

I am looking for a filled version of `\hexagon`.

I found `\Steelhexagon` from "marvosym", but in the template that I am using it seems to render as an arrow and I get conflicts because of other symbols in "marvosym". I wonder if there is a black hexagon symbol in a more common latex package.

Comment: As always on the site please provide a full (but minimal) example that others can copy and test as is. Otherwise we cannot help much. Also note that there are a **lot** of bad templates out there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As for most unicode symbols, there are filled hexagons in the STIX font.

[image]

They can be imported without importing the whole font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols4}{LS1}{stixbb}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varhexagonblack}{\mathord}{symbols4}{"DD}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\hexagonblack}   {\mathord}{symbols4}{"DE}
\begin{document}
\verb|\hexagonblack|: \( \hexagonblack \)

\verb|\varhexagonblack|: \( \varhexagonblack \)
\end{document}
```

Comment: How did you calculate the `DD` and `DE`? I the [stix documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/fonts/stix/doc/stix.pdf) I see four hexdigit codes and they seem to have nothing to do with the codes in your snippet.

Comment: @allo The four hexdigit codes you see in the documentation are the codes of the unicode symbols, and are not directly related to the font. To find the location of the symbols in the font (by that I mean these ``"DD`` and ``"DE`` codes), you can look in the file ``stix.sty``, and search for the line defining the symbol you're looking for. You should find a line ``\DeclareMathSymbol...`` like those in my answer.

Answer (score 13):

Just it is a bit complex but I had used thus how I have written in the image a combination between `tikz` and `\usetikzlibrary{shapes}` that get the hexagon symbol: `regular polygon sides=6`. After I have used `\mathord` like suggested by user @Thruston in the recent comment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\bhexagon}{\mathord{\raisebox{0.6pt}{\tikz{\node[draw,scale=.65,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,fill=black](){};}}}}

\begin{document}
\verb|tikz package with shapes|
$\triangle+\bhexagon=\square$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Remember that STIX font change also the font of the text. Thus with the previous code you have always (for example) the font computer modern with the default symbol of `amssymb`.

**ADDENDUM:** It is possibile to have another hexagon symbol with the package [`oplotsymbl`](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/oplotsymbl/oPlotSymbl-Manual-en.pdf) (using `graphicx`+`rotatebox` you can have the classic hexagon):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{oplotsymbl}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
Another option
\[\hexagofill+\diamond=\blacksquare\]
\end{document}
```

**ADDENDUM 2**: Now I have seen that exist also a new [package](https://www.math.toronto.edu/%7Edrorbn/projects/dbnsymb/dbnsymbman.pdf) called [`dbnsymb`](https://www.math.toronto.edu/%7Edrorbn/projects/dbnsymb/dbnsymbman.html) rev. 7 Mar. 2, 2020 that it give us also the symbol `\hexagon`. It is important to have `dbnsymb.sty` to use this package.

[image]

I think that using `xcolor` package this symbol can be coloured.

**ADDENDUM 3**:
Surely you can directly to use the symbol using `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX` (Unicode characters) with `fontspec`:

```
Symbol, Title/Description   Unicode Code / HTML Code
```

⬢,  Black Hexagon,  `&#11042`;  `&#x2B22`;

⬣,  Horizontal, Black Hexagon,  `&#11043`;  `&#x2B23`;

**ADDENDUM 4**: using `unicode-math` + `XITS Math`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\newcommand{\vbh}{\mathbin{\varhexagonblack}}
\newcommand{\hb}{\mathbin{\hexagonblack}}

\begin{document}
First $\hb+\vbh=\triangle$ second
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be better to use `\mathord` instead of `\mathbin` here?

Comment: @Thruston I have edited my MWE: Thank you very much for your feedback.

Comment: Hello Sebastiano!! Amazing result, congrats .

Comment: @manooooh Weeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee ahahhahah . Always kind with me.

Answer (score 9):

The STIX font also has two versions of the symbol (in different rotations). For pdfLaTeX you can use the `stix2` package. Downside is that STIX becomes the font for your entire document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix2}
\begin{document}
\(a+b=\varhexagonblack\).

\(b+a=\hexagonblack\).
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can print this symbol without any package from the font MarVoSym.ttf:

```
\font\marvosym=umvs

{\marvosym\char146}
```

Answer (score 7):

The symbols in `marvosym` are meant to be used in *text*.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\begin{document}

Wrong: \verb|$a=\HexaSteel$| $\to$ $a=\HexaSteel$

Right: \verb|$a=\text{\HexaSteel}$| $\to$ $a=\text{\HexaSteel}$

\end{document}
```

Of course, if you plan to use this as a math symbol, you can do

```
\newcommand{\hexagon}{\text{\HexaSteel}}
```

in your document preamble.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The `unicode-math` package includes all the math symbols in Unicode, under the same names as `stix` and `stix2`.  You can import them with

```
\setmathfont[ range={\hexagonblack,\varhexagonblack},
              Scale=MatchUppercase
            ]{STIX Two Math}
```

XITS Math is a fork of the STIX 1 font, and other fonts might or might not have these symbols.